# Obtener el id de un checkbox con vue js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick, vuejs

me ayudan con lo siguiente pliz

Tengo un checkbox

```
<input
    @click="updatedRole('control-de-costos-de-obra')"
    v-model="checkedNames2"
    type="checkbox"
    name="checkbox-p-2-{{$person->id}}"
    id="checkbox-p-2-{{$person->id}}"
    value="{{ $person->id}}">
```

y con vue estoy intentando recibir el valor de este de esta forma

```
updatedRole(rol){

    if((rol == 'control-de-costos-de-obra') && !this.checkedNames2[0]){
        console.log("Agregar el rol "+rol+" al id"+this.checkedNames2[0]);
        this.checkedNames2 = [];
    }
```

Pero el resultado que me da en la consola es

```
Agregar el rol administrativo-de-obra al id undefined
```

y entiendo que es porque el input checkbox esta no seleccionado, ya que tengo otra condicional donde si me da el id del checkbox checkeado

```
else if((rol == 'control-de-costos-de-obra') && this.checkedNames2[0]){
        console.log("Quitar el rol de "+rol+" al id "+this.checkedNames2[0]);
        this.checkedNames2 = [];
    }
```

y el resultado en la consola es el siguiente

```
Quitar el rol de administrativo-de-obra al id 1
```

Entonces ¿De que forma puedo obtener el id del checkbox que viene como no checkeado?

Comment: porque siempre buscas this.checkedNames2[0]? donde esta ese 0, no deberia ir el id que se recibe como parametro en la funcion? si no, siempre estas mirando el mismo valor...

Comment: Lo que sucede es que estoy recibiendo el valor y el id del checkbox con php     id="checkbox-p-2-{{$person->id}}"
    value="{{ $person->id}}" y  checkedNames2 es un v-model que es un array

Comment: Has un loop verificando la condición checked: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(){ if($(this).attr('checked')){ // lo que necesites } }; ` etc.

Comment: mmm me parece que estas mezclando las cosas. .que tiene que ver php aca con vue? vos podes mandar el id como un parametro, asi como mandas el rol...

Comment: Sucede que es una tabla con mas de 500 registros, y estoy utilizando Laravel para paginar los registros y evitar tiempo de carga de datos en la grilla del index, por eso el id del usuario lo estoy recibiendo en la vista blade con un foceach, pero el problema es como obtengo el value del checkbox noheckeado, porque obtengo el id cuando solo viene checkeado

Comment: ese input esta dentro de un v-for?

Comment: No compañero esta dentro de un foreach